# XNA: weird effect by matrixTransform of spriteBatch on isometric tile

Tags: xna, sprites, isometric

I wrote a `Camera` class that contains `Matrix` (for zooming and moving around). When I zoomed it with any zoom scale other than 1, some isometric grids becomes visible on each of my isometric tile.

```
//Camera.cs
//Producing the matrix from previously set Zoom and Location 
        public static void Update()
        {
            Transform =         Matrix.CreateTranslation(Location.X, Location.Y, 0) *
                                Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom,Zoom,1);
            InverseTransform =  Matrix.Invert(Transform);
        }






//Game.cs
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, Camera.InverseTransform);

                /* Some Drawing */

            spriteBatch.End();
```

PS: Actually, I really want these grids to be visible for zoom scale of 1.0f too. Having these grids make my game looks more like a tile-based game.

Before Zoom (Scale = 1.0f):
[image]

After Zoom (Zooming in):
[image]

After Zoom (Zooming out):
[image]

Zooming very close (Grid line appears to be more than one pixels):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be aliasing, I mean that at some magnifications the sampling of the grid just happens to skip over the lines you want.

Is it possible to make your grid line thicker than one pixel?

Comment: I'll try anti-aliasing and see the result. For grid line thicker than one pixel, I am not sure about that, but it seems to be more than one pixel as I zoom in very close.

Comment: I see!  The separating line isn't a line you're drawing but the gap between tiles.  If you can move your tiles just a wee bit further apart that will do the same thing if my idea is correct, it will give you a wider line so that when rendering it doesn't get skipped.

Comment: I post a close zoom one, so can you try inspect it and give a comment on it. thanks.

Comment: I think I drew it such that there is no gap left over (on normal zooming, ofcourse) but I don't know if the transformation does anything to my setup.

Comment: @user1542, When you start scaling textures up and down, they'll sample the colors around the pixels to know which color to use. This leads to the scaling sampling the transparent pixels you have around the actual tile. You can try and change the sampler to use something like LinearClamp or PointClamp. PointClamp will give you a more pixelized look, but it should take care of the problem. Either that, or you need to draw everything to a rendertarget and then up or down scale that rendertarget, that'll fix the issue as well.

Comment: What @William'MindWorX'Mariager said.  Or just draw the grid over your tiles yourself as another thing to render, which will give you direct control over the visual aspect.